# Creating Expression task programmatically in ssis using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Anyone know about how to create an expression task in c# to generate SSIS expression task?

Thank you.

I know about `PrecedenceConstraint`.

See my code:

```
 Executable exe1 = pkg.Executables.Add("STOCK:SQLTask");
 TaskHost TKHSQLHostMySQLTask = (TaskHost)exe1;
 TKHSQLHostMySQLTask.Name = "my sql";
 ExecuteSQLTask MySQLTask = (ExecuteSQLTask)TKHSQLHostMySQLTask.InnerObject;

 //creating Execute SQL Task       
 MySQLTask.Connection = "sourcecon";
 MySQLTask.SqlStatementSource = "select deptno from dbo.dept";
 MySQLTask.SqlStatementSourceType = SqlStatementSourceType.DirectInput;
 MySQLTask.BypassPrepare = false;      

 Executable exe2 = pkg.Executables.Add("STOCK:SQLTask");

 TaskHost TKHSQLHostMySQLTask1 = (TaskHost)exe2;
 ExecuteSQLTask MySQLTask1 = (ExecuteSQLTask)TKHSQLHostMySQLTask1.InnerObject;
 //creating Execute SQL Task       
 MySQLTask1.Connection = "sourcecon";
 MySQLTask1.SqlStatementSource = "select deptno from dbo.dept where deptname=?";
 MySQLTask1.SqlStatementSourceType = SqlStatementSourceType.DirectInput;
 MySQLTask1.BypassPrepare = false;

 // Add input parameter binding
 MySQLTask1.ParameterBindings.Add();
 IDTSParameterBinding parameterBinding = MySQLTask1.ParameterBindings.GetBinding(0);
 parameterBinding.DtsVariableName = "[User::Dname]";
 parameterBinding.ParameterDirection = ParameterDirections.Input;
 //parameterBinding.DataType = (int)OleDBDataTypes.VARCHAR;
 parameterBinding.ParameterName = "0";
 parameterBinding.ParameterSize = 255;

 PrecedenceConstraint pc = pkg.PrecedenceConstraints.Add((Executable)exe1, (Executable)exe2);
 pc.EvalOp = DTSPrecedenceEvalOp.ExpressionAndConstraint;
 pc.Expression ="[User::myVar]>0";
  //how to add Expression task ?
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you targeting?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no published [moniker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135956.aspx) for an `ExpressionTask` in SSIS 2012. Use the CLSID of the `ExpressionTask` executable instead. You can then use the `PrecedenceConstraint` to connect it to other classes. See the example below.

Make sure you reference `Microsoft.SqlServer.ExpressionTask` assembly in your project.

```
// Using the CLSID
Executable exExpressionTask = 
pkg.Executables.Add("Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ExpressionTask.ExpressionTask, Microsoft.SqlServer.ExpressionTask, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91");
TaskHost thExpressionTask = exExpressionTask as TaskHost;
ExpressionTask expressionTask = thExpressionTask.InnerObject as ExpressionTask;

// Set the expression.
expressionTask.Expression = @"10>0";

// Get the expression.
string expression = expressionTask.Expression;

// Validate the expression.
string str = expressionTask.ValidateExpression(null);
```

Comment: @Sunil Sambarekar Thanks. Mark it as the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: @ Jamleck Thanks. how to "Mark it as the answer"? How to do it?

Comment: Any one can know about derived new column takes source EmpID column. my code gives bellow error-
Attempt to find the input column named "EmpID" failed with error code 0xC0010009. The input column specified was not found in the input column collection.

Comment: Please post this as a separate question.

Comment: I solved this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166854/ssis-how-to-programatically-genrate-derived-new-columnrowkey-that-takes-input